# Is there way to cut iterator by another iterator in rust?

Tags: rust, iterator

I want to cut the iterator by another. Pictorial example:

```
let it = non_sliceable_container.iter();
while predicate(it.next(), ...) {
  // ...
}
let prefix = non_sliceable_container.iter().set_end(it); // <- want something like this
for val in prefix {
  // ...
}
/*
works as
let prefix = container.iter();
while  prefix != it {
  let val = prefix.next();
  // ...
}
*/
```

It seems possible because only immutable references are present.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking. It looks more like what you want to accomplish is splitting your container. Why don't you just do the work in the second loop inside the first loop? Please provide a more complete example.

Comment: @PitaJ, I want to find someplace in the iterator of the container which is not sliceable (fix the question), and go to that place again with some actions, and this actions can't be done in the first loop.

Comment: It's still not clear what you want to accomplish. Please provide an example with inputs, predicates, and your expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that I misunderstood rust's iterators: I thought that it's possible to compare iterators like in c++ (e.g. check if it's iterators of the same container and on same position). It's not true. So the solution to this situation is following:

```
let it = non_sliceable_container.iter();
let counter = 0usize;
while predicate(it.next(), ...) {
  // ...
  counter += 1;
}
let prefix = non_sliceable_container.iter().take(counter);
for val in prefix {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you're wanting to move `it` while some `predicate` is true, and then iterate from the beginning of the container to where `it` is? You should just be able to iterate with `take_while`:

```
for val in container.iter().take_while(predicate) {
  // ..
}
```

Comment: No, I must do some work in `while loop` in which predicate calculating (for performance reasons) and it can't be done with `take_while`, but it can be done with counter and simple `take` (see my answer to myself)